# php function to list months for dropdown

Tags: php

I have this function

```
function bookingMonthField() {
$str="";
        for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') + $i);
        $str .="<option value=" . date('Yn', $time) . ">" . date('M Y', $time) . "</option>";   
    }
  return $str;
  }
```

Which works (almost) as it should, except it is returning no Feb and 2x March:

```
<option value="20119">Sep 2011</option>
<option value="201110">Oct 2011</option>
<option value="201111">Nov 2011</option>
<option value="201112">Dec 2011</option>
<option value="20121">Jan 2012</option>
<option value="20123">Mar 2012</option>
<option value="20123">Mar 2012</option>
<option value="20124">Apr 2012</option>
<option value="20125">May 2012</option>
<option value="20126">Jun 2012</option>
<option value="20127">Jul 2012</option>
<option value="20128">Aug 2012</option>
<option value="20129">Sep 2012</option>
<option value="201210">Oct 2012</option>
<option value="201211">Nov 2012</option>
<option value="201212">Dec 2012</option>
```

ANy ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Today is the end of the month. Imagine how many days February has.

Comment: You could use [`strtotime('Sep 1 2012 + 1 month')`](http://codepad.org/pnov8eqx), probably be easier.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: it would be if he alwas needed 16 months since september 2012

Comment: @zerkms - Althought [this will work](http://codepad.org/XFYGbarN), it's debatable whether that's "easier" than using `mktime()`. I would say it's easier to read. (And it [would be easier](http://codepad.org/rsltG51D), if `first monday` returned the current month's first monday, not the next first monday, at least on the last day of the month.)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: yep, *now* it is easier ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell your script, you want the first of the month:

```
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') + $i, 1);
```

Or wait another day, then your website is automatically fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

`mktime` will use the current day if none is provided.  Today is the 29th, so February is skipped.  Instead, specify "1" for the day.